# UI2D Sprite incorrectly displays a texture. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I have UI2D Sprite and Texture. Result - 
[image]
Original texture is circle.
Why is that? Help me please.
P.s. Some textures are displayed correctly and some incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

I had similar issue and I was able to come to conclusion, that some times Unity expands the texture size to closest multiplication of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16 ...). For example if you have texture sized 100x200 it expanded to 128x256. This should be more optimal for GPUs, but the problem is how the expansion is done by Unity. It adds multiplications of top row on the top of the image and multiplications of rightmost cell to the right of the image. That is why you see the circle exploding.

### Solution

My dirty hack was to resize or expand textures myself to multiplication of 2 with Photoshop. I also tried changing the import settings of the image, but did not find any better solution. In addition, I noticed that even textures looked bad on the editor they were completely fine on my testing Android device.